# To retrieve docs by time of index is there a better approach?

Tags: google-app-engine

For each doc I'm indexing with App Engine Search I'm including the following:

```
search.NumberField(name='created_on', value=created_on_epoch),
search.NumberField(name='modified_on', value=modified_on_epoch),
```

The two values are calculated from 1/1/1970 so I can filter/sort results based on 'freshness'.

My question: have I missed any built-in App Engine Search feature that already encodes time of indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you need is to filter on freshness, just have an iterated index that increments with every new document you add.  If you don't care about the actual date, just the order, you won't need to save all these.

That'll work for "created on".  You'll still need to create the modified on I think.  I know of no built in feature for time in the search API

Comment: There is no need to have a "created on" field if no other ranking is used.

Answer (score 0):

Search API already ranks documents by the time they were indexed. This is the default ranking unless you specify your own. You do not need to add any fields for that.